# How can I remove/delete a virtual python environment created with virtualenv in Windows 10?

Tags: python, cmd, virtualenv, command-prompt

I want to learn how to remove a virtual environment using the windows command prompt, I know that I can easily remove the folder of the environment. But I want to know if there is a more professional way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command to remove virtualenv, you can deactivate it or remove the folder but unfortunately virtualenv library doesn't contain any kind of removal functionality.

Comment: So removing the environment folder is the only way to do it.
Okay thank you!